# Getting values from checkbox, add them, and display the result (REACT)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have data in json format and it has amount. I mapped it in table with a checkbox per row.

eg of my data:

```
[
 {
  subscriberId: 1001,
  amount: 100
},
{
  subscriberId: 1002,
  amount: 123
},
{
  subscriberId: 1003,
  amount: 122
}]
```

I want to get the sum of amount of the checked box I selected. I am using reactJs. How can I do this. I'm new in react. thank you.

Comment: @brk done editing it.  i just mapped it already, i just want to know on how can i get the value of what i checked and then get the sum of it.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: just push your selected box in array and calculate sum inside onchange function of checkbox button   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by storing all selected items in a state and then using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the sum of all selected items.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      subscriberId: 1001,
      amount: 100,
    },
    {
      subscriberId: 1002,
      amount: 300,
    },
    {
      subscriberId: 1003,
      amount: 500,
    },
  ];
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (item, checked) =>
    checked
      ? setChecked((prev) => [...prev, item])
      : setChecked((prev) =>
          prev.filter((c) => c.subscriberId !== item.subscriberId && c.amount != item.amount)
        );

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((c) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleChange(c, e.target.checked)} />
            {`subscriber ${c.subscriberId}, amount ${c.amount}`}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <p>Total {checked.reduce((sum, { amount }) => sum + amount, 0)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note that the logic in this example will not be flawless if you have duplicate objects (i.e., identical subscriberId and amount). In that case, the unchecking of one box will lead to the subtraction of the amounts of all those identical objects and your UI (visible checkboxes) and data state will be out of sync.

Comment: thanks bro for the effort, this works. I consider this as your gift because its my birthday today.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing it. I would suggest implementing a useMemo(more applicable in this case) or useEffect with the checked list in dependencies array as second param; as it would execute the sum calculation logic only when the user interacts.

Please find codesandbox link with demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-issue-68570487-f4q1u?file=/src/checkboxGroup.js

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate the `data` and create the checkbox and then use `useState` to update the totalAmount

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from 'react';

export function CheckBox() {
  const data = [{
    subscriberId: 1001,
    amount: 100
  }, {
    subscriberId: 1002,
    amount: 123
  }, {
    subscriberId: 1003,
    amount: 122
  }]
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0)

  function updateTotal(e, amount) {
    setTotalAmount((totalAmount) => {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + amount;
        return totalAmount
      } else {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - amount;
        return totalAmount
      }
    });
  }

  return ( <div>
    <div>
     {totalAmount}
    </div> {
      data.map((item, index) => {
            return ( <div>
              <input type = 'checkbox'
              key = {
                item.subscriberId
              }
              value = {
                item.amount
              }
              id = {
                item.subscriberId
              }
              onChange = {
                (e) => {
                  updateTotal(e, item.amount)
                }
              }/>
              </div>)
            })
        } 
        </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add them on the array and then use useState to add the value of checkbox using reduce